# How to install a zip package in Pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I am using Pycharm IDE. I am doing a project that requires an older version of Tensorflow. I tried installing in from within pycharm marketplace using specified versions, but it says that there is no matching distributions found. So, I downloaded Tensorflow v1.8 sourcecode from Github as a zip. Now I want to install it in pycharm. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an IDE with things like a 'marketplace' is nice in theory, but you'll always end up having to resort to the commandline. Try to open the Terminal in PyCharm, it should activate with the python environment of your project. Then install tensorflow 1.8 with `pip install tensorflow==1.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version

`pip install tensorflow`

For the previous ones

```
pip install tensorflow==THE VERSION YOU WANT

pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

Or with pyCharm

`Preferences> Project: PROJECT NAME> Python interpreter`

Click on the `+` symbol at the top left and look for the package you want to install

(At the bottom right you can also check the Specify version box and choose the version you prefer)